# How to redirect to home URL after Django Allauth login with Google?

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I'm using Django Allauth to provide Google authentication for my website.

Everything is working fine, except that I get redirected to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=2CXclEHzhr58&code=4%2F0Adeu5BW1_2pqwk7edcaJ7nLR7b8hmBcfRX2_605538Il2j3dWc0jYwWzEbwV10mMnmI2oA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=2&prompt=consent#
```

instead of just **127.0.0.1:8000/** even tho I set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"`.

The redirect itself works fine, in the sense that I get the home page, but is there a way to also have the link be just `127.0.0.1:8000/?` Otherwise, do you know of any alternatives I could use?

I'm also thinking this could be caused by Google's API, but can't tell how.

Thanks in advance!

Tried to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"` and `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "home"`

Comment: Do you have a return redirect in your callback function?